# MacBook Pro 2018 Spectre/Meltdown

Tags: macos, mac, bios, meltdown, spectre

I have a question about the Spectre/Meltdown security on Mac. 
To mitigate the problem I guess also the microcode update of the processor is needed.

How does Apple handle this? Do I need to update BIOS manually or is everything done automatically?

Does the MacBookPro 2018 get the microcode updates?

Comment: [Information](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT208394)

Comment: [More info here](https://www.macrumors.com/2018/01/23/macos-sierra-el-capitan-spectre-meltdown-fixes/): “Apple in early January confirmed that all of its Mac and iOS devices were impacted, but Meltdown mitigations were introduced ahead of when the vulnerabilities came to light in iOS 11.2 and macOS 10.13.2, and Spectre was addressed through Safari updates in iOS 11.2.2 and a macOS 10.13.2 Supplemental Update.”